# Special charts in yaml key: Pipeline Utility Steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am using the **Pipeline Utility Steps** to read and updated the yaml files in my repo. However there is one key (chart-name) which has "-" (not "_", I know this is not preferred but its there). Now the problem i am facing is that "-" is considered as "binary expression" and its giving the error.
'''

```
script {
  def filename = "values.yaml"
  def data = readYaml file: filename
  data.chart-name.image.image = "imange name"
  sh "rm $filename"
  writeYaml file: filename, data: data
 }
```

'''
Error:
(data.chart - name.image.ports.containerPort) is a binary expression, but it should be a variable expression at line: 96 column: 51. File: WorkflowScript @ line 96, column 51.
   name.image.ports.containerPort = "${param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the quotation syntax for accessing Map-like objects in Groovy, e.g.:

```
data.'chart-name'.image.image = "image name"
```

Of course, you might want to make sure nothing on that chain returns a null value...

Comment: thanks for the help.. it worked well. Since i used helm, I cant use "_" in many cases. Your answered helped a lot.